# Can't connect ethernet to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: ethernet

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm having some trouble connecting a stand alone Ubuntu device to the internet to download some necessary updates for the system. I apologize in advance for the lack of screenshots, but I will do my best to type out the relevant information that might be helpful.

First of all, in the bottom right it shows the symbol that I am connected to the network, and when I go into 'Network connections', 'Wired connection 1' says last used now. However, upon clicking 'Connection Information" I get an error which is "No valid active connections found!"

The command ifconfig -a yields the following

---

```
enp1s0: Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 1c:21:d1:d0:01:2f    
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1    
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0     
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0    
RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp2s0: Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 1c:21:d1:df:fc:3b    
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1    
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0    
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0    
RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  

lo: Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0    
RX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0    
TX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1    
RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

From some other posts I gathered that I think the network is recognized, but not connected so I tried to save set the network preferences by typing sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces and entering the next two lines

---

```
auto enp1s0    
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```

---

I've also tried the same code with enp2s0 instead, and unfortunately I still can't connect. Any ideas on how to proceed, or if I need to provide any additional info? For what it's worth, I plug the same ethernet cable into my Windows desktop for internet access, so I don't think it's anything like having a bad cable. I appreciate the help!